# removing an option with menuconfig (dependency)

Tags: makefile, openwrt

I am building openwrt for Linkit smart with ***make menuconfig***. 
I am trying to remove python from build, but python is marked with (**-*-**).
This means another package depends on python.

I tried to search with (/) for python but could not find a clue on that package.

Is there away to find which package (or other item) that depends on python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.
Just highlight the suspected item and press (?)
The popup window will show you :

- what other items this item (selects).
- what other items has (selected) this item (dependencies).

Then you can go back and deselect those items that depend on this.